# How to refer to multiple files from a directory to one command

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a command that needs to take multiple input files, which are originally from one directory and have certain file name patterns. For example:

In directory

```
/home/mydir/
```

I have files:

```
A.dat
B.dat
C.dat
readme.doc
```

I would like to learn how to pass all files with ending of ".dat" to this command, which then should look like:

```
command A.dat B.dat C.dat > /home/outputdir/output.dat
```

I could do it in python e.g. by storing the file names in a list, but how should I do it in shell please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm puzzled why a simple shell glob such as `?.dat` or possibly even `*.dat` wouldn't be acceptable. Helene, you do know that the shell itself expands a wildcard pattern and passes the matching set of files to the `command`, don't you...?

Comment: Thank you@roaima I didn't know that. I'm very new to shell script and thanks very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard UNIX shell will do something called [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion); this uses special characters to mean, for example, one character (`?`) or any number of characters (`*`). To use your example, you could run (where the initial `$` represents your command prompt and not something you'd type):

```
$ command /home/mydir/*.dat > /home/outputdir/output.dat
```

Your shell will expand that to:

```
$ command /home/mydir/A.dat /home/mydir/B.dat /home/mydir/C.dat > /home/outputdir/output.dat
```

before actually calling the command. The `*` says "take any and all filenames in /home/mydir that end with ".dat".

For some variations of the command, given the same input files:

```
# all of the sample input files have a single letter before the ".dat"
$ command /home/mydir/?.dat > /home/outputdir/output.dat

# the square brackets say "any (one) of these characters"
$ command /home/mydir/[ABC].dat > /home/outputdir/output.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on what tool you're trying to use.  Some are designed to accept multiple files as parameters, which can be done with:

```
/path/to/some/tool file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/lotsafiles/*
```

Others are designed to only accept one file as a parameter, and so will have to be repeatedly invoked with each file you want to address, which would be done thusly:

```
for file in file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/lotsafiles/*; do
    /path/to/some/tool "$file"
done
```

To know whether or not you must only specify one file at a time, see the program's manual page (`man tool`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the tool could (in fact, have to) take multiple files, so I believe no loop is needed - but the problem here is that i need to a good way to locate these files. I don't know their name beforehand.